# Populate vectors with 2 for loops

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I may be misunderstanding how for loops work, but I'm having hard time comprehending why the current code doesn't populate vectors (the vectors evidently remain NA, although the code itself runs). I imagine there may also be a way to subset all of this information using ifelse(), but I'm experiencing "coder's block".

**Issue (elaborated):** I am trying to code a running Electoral College projection based on a betting market from the 2008 presidential cycle, over the final 90 days until Election Day. I justify using two for loops because the code needs to check conditional statements on a particular day and add a particular value to a preexisting sum at on that day. In other words, if the betting price for Obama is higher than McCain on a particular for a particular state that state's electoral votes are awarded to Obama on that day, and visa versa. Again, the code runs, but the vectors apparently remain NA.

**Key of Relevant Variables**

EV, electoral votes of that particular state
X, a unique value assigned to each observation
day, date class
PriceD, betting price for the Dem candidate
PriceR, betting price for the Rep candidate
DaysToEday, a numeric value indicating the difference between variable day and election day (2008-11-04)

**Code in Question**

```
Obama08.ECvotesByDay <- McCain08.ECvotesByDay <- rep(NA, 90)

for (i in 1:90) {

  for (j in 1:nrow(subset(mpres08, mpres08$DaysToEday <= 90))){
       
  if(mpres08$PriceD[j] > mpres08$PriceR[j]) {
    Obama08.ECvotesByDay[i] <- Obama08.ECvotesByDay[i]+mpres08$EV[j]

  }

  else {

    McCain08.ECvotesByDay[i] <- McCain08.ECvotesByDay[i]+mpres08$EV[j]

  }
  }
}
```

**dput of Data** (five rows)

```
structure(list(state = c("AK", "AK", "AK", "AK", "AK"), state.name = c("Alaska", 
"Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska", "Alaska"), Obama = c(38L, 38L, 
38L, 38L, 38L), McCain = c(59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L), EV = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), X = c(24073L, 25195L, 8773L, 25603L, 25246L), 
    day = structure(c(13937, 13959, 13637, 13967, 13960), class = "Date"), 
    PriceD = c(7.5, 7.5, 10, 8, 7.5), VolumeD = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), PriceR = c(92.5, 92.5, 90, 92, 92.5), VolumeR = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DaysToEday = c(250, 228, 550, 220, 227)), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Obama08.ECvotesByDay[i]` and `McCain08.ECvotesByDay[i]` are initialised with `NA`. In R, if you try to do arithmetic with `NA` it stays `NA` (e.g. `NA + 1` results in `NA`). Depending on what is a neutral result for you, you could initialise the vectors in the beginning with 0:

```
Obama08.ECvotesByDay <- McCain08.ECvotesByDay <- rep(0, 90)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a number to NA, and for R the result is NA.